# Length of depletion region in pn junction

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

The formula to calculate the length of depletion region is:

$X_{depletion}=\sqrt{2q\epsilon _{Si}(\frac{1}{N_{d}}-\frac{1}{N_{A}})(\phi _{i}-V_{a})}$

Some exercises ask me to calculate $X_{depletion}$ when $V_{a}>\phi _{i}$ and then negative number in the square root.

Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what $\phi_{i}$ actually is?

I have only seen this equation written as:

$X_{depletion} = \sqrt{\frac{2\epsilon_{Si}}{q} (\frac{1}{N_{A}} + \frac{1}{N_D} )V_{bi}}$ where $V_{bi}$ is the built in potential and is always positive.

Comment: Oh sorry,The equation written in my post is wrong since the charge q i divided. Phi_i is the built in voltage and V_a is the voltage applied by a source.

Comment: @Mattteo, if you realize the equation in the original post is incorrect, it's a good idea to edit the post and correct it.